# What is the order of these quest triggers?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

I recently started playing *Xenoblade Chronicles* on the 3DS and I am feeling a bit overwhelmed with all of the quests since they are available at different times of day and can unlock in areas I have already been.

Using the information I found on the [Xenoblade wikia](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Quest), I was able to write a program to make the data more manageable. I am able to get a master list of the quest triggers thanks to the breakdown provided per region, but I don't know their ordering in relation to the other triggers from other regions. Here is a master list of all the quest triggers among the different regions *in order of region where first found and occurrence order within that region*:

```
Available at the start
After meeting Reyn at the Weapon Dev. Lab
After beginning the trip to Colony 6
After Sharla Joins
After reaching the Colony 6 area
After reaching Satorl Marsh
After cutscene at the Sororal Statues
After reaching Makna Forest
After Melia Joins
After Riki Joins
After Mechonis Core
After reaching Vilia Lake in Tephra Cave
After reaching the Bionis' Leg
After Colony 6 reconstruction begins
After reaching Eryth Sea
After Prison Island
After meeting Miqol in the Hidden Village
After reaching the Central Factory
After the attack on Colony 6
After reaching Frontier Village
After unlocking access to Valak Mountain
After reaching Alcamoth
After reaching Valak Mountain
While traveling to Prison Island
After leaving for the High Entia Tomb
After reaching Sword Valley
After reaching Galahad Fortress
After reaching Fallen Arm
After reaching the Hidden Village
After unlocking access to Mechonis Field
After reaching Agniratha
After reaching the Ventilation Conduit
During Mechonis Core
Second visit to Prison Island
```

**What is the actual order of these events over the course of the game?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now after having time to play the game myself, I can confirm the following order of events:

```
Available at the start
After meeting Reyn at the Weapon Dev. Lab
After beginning the trip to Colony 6
After reaching Vilia Lake in Tephra Cave
After reaching the Bionis' Leg
After Sharla Joins
After reaching the Colony 6 area
After reaching Satorl Marsh
After cutscene at the Sororal Statues
After Colony 6 reconstruction begins
After reaching Makna Forest
After Melia Joins
After reaching Frontier Village
After Riki Joins
After reaching Eryth Sea
After reaching Alcamoth
After leaving for the High Entia Tomb
While unlocking access to Prison Island
After Prison Island
After unlocking access to Valak Mountain
After reaching Valak Mountain
After reaching Sword Valley
After reaching Galahad Fortress
After reaching Fallen Arm
After reaching the Hidden Village
After meeting Miqol in the Hidden Village
After unlocking access to Mechonis Field
After reaching the Central Factory
After reaching Agniratha
After reaching the Ventilation Conduit
During Mechonis Core
After Mechonis Core
After the attack on Colony 6
Second visit to Prison Island
```